# Spring hateoas with complete Restful service spec

Tags: hateoas

Along with link in hateoas, How can we pass the request spec like whether attribute is required, format, possible domain values?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article about enabling Swagger. @EnableSwagger2. That is the way for documenting the Restful services.